# accessing variables among multiple classes in Java

Tags: java, oop, variables, methods

Let's say I have 3 different classes:

**Class Person**,
**Class Room**,
**Class House**.

They are linked like this:

in class **House** I do: `Room room = new Room();`
in class **Room** I do: `Person person = new Person();`

In Person I have this method:

```
public String getName(){
 return name;
}
```

How can I access this method from class **House**?

The way I do it now is to repeat the method in class **Room** like:

```
public String getName(){
 return person.getName();
}
```

So in **House** I call the `getName()` method from **Room**, and in **Room** I call the method `getName()` from **Person**. So the name-variable is then passed from **Person** via **Room** to **House**!

But this way I'm duplicating all methods from Person that I need to access in House. This can't be right.... I thought about 'extending', but that doesn't make sense.
Can someone please explain to me (I now have a lot of methods dupplicated in my code).
It may be basic OOP stuff, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure, getName() and getPerson() are both public. That way House can access them.

Comment: @Legend, I edited the methods from private to public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this way I'm duplicating all methods from Person that I need to
>   access in House. This can't be right....

You're right. You don't need to do that. That is not the correct way.

Since you are having a `Person` reference in `Room` class, you just need to define a "getter" for `person`: -

```
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
```

And then form your `House` class, you can get `person` name and other details like this: -

```
room.getPerson().getName();
room.getPerson().getAge();
```

So, basically, you are getting a copy of `person` reference (Not the copy of person instance itself) of your `room` instance, in your `House` class. And then using that reference, as if it were defined in `House` class only.

One more point, I saw that your getters are private. You should not do that. Make them public, else they won't be accessible outside. `getters` and `setters` should almost always be public.

Comment: Maybe you should point out that returning "a copy of person reference" does not actually involve creating a copy of person. I think that's not really obvious for someone who isn't used to the "everything is a reference" concept of Java.

Comment: Wow.. thanks this is the thing I was looking for. How is it called in OOP terms? I've been searching for this info for weeks... And is it returning the 'type' of the last Method in the call: room.getPerson().getName() (will return a String, not Person).

Comment: @BoudewijnCorbach.. YEs it will return String. The name of the person only.

Comment: @BoudewijnCorbach.. There is as such no OOP term for this. It's just method-chaining.

Answer (score 1):

Expose person as a property of Room.

What you have is a bit weird because one would expect room.getName() to return the room's name.

Instead Room should have a getPerson() method so when a person name is needed, room.getPerson().getName()

Comment: To hide the existence of the class Person as an implementation detail of Room, you could name the method room.getTenantName().

Comment: getTennantName() should always return "David" but getTenantName() would work